# Emberjs route with args fail in some case

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

In some case I got an issue with the routing url. Here's my router :

```js
contacts: Em.Route.extend({
    route: '/contacts',

    index: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            App.contactsController.populate()
            var appController = router.get('applicationController');
            appController.connectOutlet('contactsList');
        }
    }),

    show: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/:contactid',
        connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            alert('show contact');
        }
    }),

    doShowContact: function(router, event){
        router.transitionTo('show', {contactid: event.context.id});
    }
}),
```

When I enter inside doShowContact, if I specify **'contactid'** as context and **'/:contactid'** as route inside 'show', I'll get for example **'/contacts/3'** in the browser url, everything is ok.

However in doShowContact, if I specify **'contact_id'** rather than **'contactid'** as context and **'/:contact_id'** rather than **'/:contactid'** as route. I'll get **'/contacts/undefined'** in the browser url.

Is there a way to explain it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply pass the contact instance, not forge an object with `contactid` property:

```js
doShowContact: function(router, event) {
  var contact = event.context;
  router.transitionTo('show', contact);
}
```

You should also specify the `modelClass` property in your route:

```js
show: Em.Route.extend({
  route: '/:contact_id',
  modelClass: App.Contact,

  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. It works better now. Is it important to specify a modelClass in the route ?

Comment: The class will be used for model instance lookup (ember-data model's find)

Comment: @Thomas the model class will is extracted from the name of the parameter: `user_id` will assume the model `YourNamespace.User` whereas `repository_id` will asume `YourNamespace.Repository`. If you use this convention, specifying the `modelClass` explicitly is not required.