# Proper way to use parent route parameters with ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-old-router

In my app, I am trying to keep the routing structure as close to the API structure as possible, which ember facilitates in the basic case but I am still confused about the following case:

(In reference to the example of http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_nesting)

What is the best way to go about retrieving the `/posts/:post_id/comments` data (assuming it isn't given to me by `/posts/:post_id`)?

Should I be passing the post ID to `App.Comment.find(...)` somehow, in the `comments.deserialize(...)` method? Is there a better way to get the post ID than `router.getPath('postController.content._id')`? I am using a modified DS.RESTAdapter.

Comment: when you route to /posts/:post_id/comments connectOutlets for parent (/posts/:post_id) must be called first. May be this can help

Comment: For the answer for the new Router see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15225128/1474739

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parent router parameters are no more accessible as parameters in children routes, but should have been used to retrieve and populate intermediate data structure.

Given your models are defined as follow:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  // ...
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  // You may also have: "post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')", but we do not care for this exemple
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  // ...
});
```

This should be something working:

```
posts: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: 'posts',

  member: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/:post_id', // [A]

    connectOutlets: function (router, post) {
      var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
      applicationController.connectOutlet('post', post); // [B]
    },

    show: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    }),

    comments: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: 'comments',

      connectOutlets: function (router) {
        var postController = router.get('postController'),
            comments = postController.get('comments'); // [C]
        postController.connectOutlet('comments', comments);
      },
    }),
  })
})
```

- [A]: The post model instance will be retrieved automagically by the router, according to convention: `post_id` refers to `Post` model instance with the given `id` (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684615/emberjs-route-with-args-fail-in-some-case/11686360#comment15502304_11686360)).
- [B]: Here, `PostController` will be populated by the router with the passed context: `post`, which is the `Post` instance retrieved upper (see [A]).
- [C]: `PostController` is an `ObjectController` (i.e `Proxy`) on the post model instance, so it directly holds comments.

Comment: I understand this in terms of the routing bit (and after reading this post, a bit better), but I still need the comments data from API endpoint /posts/[post_id]/comments. It doesn't come with the /posts/[post_id] response in the case of this API -- there is only a URL but not the data. What exactly does DS.hasMany (without the embedded flag) do? Thanks for the help.