# Ember.js New Router: accessing serialized objects from parent dynamic route segments

Tags: ember.js

There was a similar [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1334) already.

Assuming the following routes:

```
App.Router.map(function (match) {
  match('/').to('index');
  match('/posts').to('posts', function (match) {
    match('/').to('postsIndex');
    match('/:post_id').to('post', function (match) {
      match('/comments').to('comments', function (match) {
        match('/').to('commentsIndex');
        match('/:comment_id').to('showComment');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Is it possible to access both `post_id` and `comment_id` in `ShowCommentRoute`? Otherwise should I forget about composite keys in my models?

Why `CommentsRoute#model(params)` and `CommentsIndexRoute` argument is always empty? How to retrieve `Post`'s comments when?

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGgxK/18/).

Run this [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RGgxK/18/show/#/posts/1/comments/1) too (there are console log showing the problem.

**UPDATE after some investigation:**

Only `PostRoute` will have `params.post_id`.
Only `ShowCommentRoute` will have `params.comment_id` and will not have `params.post_id`.

This is unacceptable for applications where models have composite keys. In case when we are transitioning to `showComment` step by step, we can obtain `Comment` instance:

```
App.ShowCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var post_id = this.controllerFor('post').get('content.id');
    return App.Comment.find(post_id, params.comment_id);
  }
});
```

But this won't work if we directly visiting `/posts/1/comments/1`. In this case `this.controllerFor('post')` always `undefined`.

- If you have nested routes with dynamic segments you **can not** access this segments in `*IndexRoute` (`PostRoute` and `PostInderRoute` in this example)
- Shortly, it's impossible to obtain parent route model when **directly visiting** nested route.

Answer (score 13):

Using ember-1.0.0-rc.1 it is now possible to access the parent route's model when directly visiting a url.

```
App.ShowCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var post = this.modelFor('post');
    return App.Comment.find(post.get('id'), params.comment_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Likewise, lifesaver answer to something that baffled me for a lot of time.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with the 1.0.0 release?

Comment: @Ben Nope. Will try to find if this is referenced in the transition guide.